# Text classification with Naive Bayes

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-classification, textblob

I am leaning NLP and noticed that TextBlob classification based in Naive Bayes (textblob is Build on top of NLTK) https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html works fine when training data is list of sentences and does not work at all when training data are individual words (where each word and assigned classification).

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have single words in the training data.

Usually the training and evaluation/testing data are supposed to be selected with identical distribution. Biases or skews are usually problematic. In very few cases you can train the model to do one thing and use it to do something else.

In your case, the model likely spreads the weights over the words in the sentence. So when you pick a single word, you only get a small portion of the weight represented.

To get it to work you should add single word examples to your training data.

Comment: Thank you, but let me clarify. I replace all sentences in training data with individual words instead (essentially by splitting exisifing sentences to words). So my training data are only words. As soon as I do this (even though the ultimate list of words is not changed) classification works substenially worse. So my question is whether classification like this can work with individual words only.

Comment: It can work, but I wouldn't expect to be very good. I don't think a human could do very well in that case either. For it to work decently, words need to be strongly correlated with the labels.